# How can I show a hidden link in a jQuery table

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a cell in a jQuery table where I've placed two hidden links. After button click I want to show them if there is something inside of description(tag with "desc_NumW" class), how can I change css of my links "Details" and "Clear"?

**my code:**

```
trow.append('<td valign="top" style="padding:2px; width:150px; height:100px">' +
  '<div class="ui-widget">' +
  '<input  size="10" maxlength="10" id="tagsW" class="tags" />' +
  '<input type="button" id="addBtn" class="addEvent" size="5" value="+" /><br/>' +
  '<div style="text-align:center" id="wedVal" class="desc_NumW">' + val.Wednesday +
  '</div >' +
  '<input type="hidden" class="idEvent" />' +
  '<div >' +
  '<a  href="#" style="float:left;text-align:left;visibility:hidden;" 
  class = "details" > Details < a / > ' + ' < a href = "#"
  style = "float:right;text- 
  align: right; visibility: hidden;
  " class="
  clear ">Clear<a />' +
  '</div >' +
  '</div >' +
  '</td>');
```

and here is my **"onclick"** function:

```
tab.on("click", ".addEvent", function(e) {
  var id = $(this).closest("div").find(".idEvent").val();
  var field = $(this).closest("div").find(".desc_NumW");
  var select = $(this).closest("div").find(".tags");
  var details = $(this).closest("div").find(".details");
  var clear = $(this).closest("div").find(".clear");
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Home/AutoEventDetails",
    data: {
      id: id
    },
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data) {
      var res = $('<p>' + data.Title + '<br/>' + data.Description + '<br/>' +
        data.Location + '</p>');
      field.html(res);
      select.val('');
    }
  });
});
```

Any idea?

Comment: This is literally something people have been asking for the last 13 years everywhere on the internet. https://google.com/?q=how+to+change+css+using+jquery

Comment: XD, sorry I'm not really a big expert in this. But thanks, I've found an answer

Comment: var btns = $(this).closest("div").find(".buttons");

Comment: an then btns.css("visibility", "visible");